# Try, Except: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table:

Tags: sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having some problems with my flask application which I never had before until today and I haven't changed anything so it's quite confusing

So it my app.py

```
@app.route('/view.html')
def data():
    try:
        path = 'app/database.db'
        con = sqlite3.connect(path)
        cur = con.cursor()

        con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        rows = cur.execute("select * from table").fetchall()
        return render_template('layouts/default.html',
                               content=render_template('pages/view.html',
                                                       rows=rows))

    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
        return render_template('layouts/default.html',
                               content=render_template('pages/view.html'))
```

The idea is that if there is no table in the database yet, it will catch the error and just return the view.html with no data but for some reason it does not work anymore

Just realised I completely forgot to add the error, my bad

```
[2020-02-22 23:56:26,209] ERROR in app: Exception on /favicon.ico [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File " -directory- ", line 316, in index
    rows = cur.execute("select * from table")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: table

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File " -directory- /app/views.py", line 337, in index
    content=render_template('pages/' + path))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 138, in render_template
    ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 60, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 89, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: pages/favicon.ico
```

And just to note, the app runs fine on localhost, it just shows error now when it never did before

Comment: What happens instead? What error do you get?

Comment: @Jacobm001 Sorry about that I just added it